# Merge intersecting surfaces (not co-planar)

Tags: bezier-curves

I have thickened two intersecting curves using "bevel_depth". I would like to know if I could merge the results to obtain one surface?

Thanks

Comment: you can only merge curves by one of their 2 tips, if it's not what you want here you need first to convert them to meshes

Comment: Oh, can I merge them after they've been thickened?

Comment: as I said, if you keep them as curves you can only join their tips. If you want to join some curves intersection you need first to convert them to meshes, then you'll be able to merge with a boolean operation